# Cat, Grep, Redirect Output.... Blank File?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, cat

I just ran

```
cat /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log | grep -v 'Apple'
```

and I got the output on the cli that I was expecting, which was all the lines in `readme.log` that did not contain '`Apple`'...

Next I ran...

```
cat /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log | grep -v 'Apple' > /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log
```

However, `/opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log` is blank.

Can anyone explain to me why this happened, or the correct way I should have gone about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/bash-redirect-input-from-file-back-into-same-file

Comment: you are trying you read and write the same file and bash processes redirection first (right-to-left)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happened because the first thing `>` does is to create the file it wants to write to - and if the file already exists, its contents will be deleted. (Also, there's no need at all to use `cat` in your statement since `grep` works on files, not just on STDIN.)

The correct way to do this is to use a temporary file either to read from or to write to. So either

```
cp /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log /tmp/readme.log
grep -v 'Apple' /tmp/readme.log > /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log
```

or

```
grep -v 'Apple' /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log > /tmp/readme.log
mv /tmp/readme.log /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log
```

would work.

Comment: or just use `>>`

Comment: @avtomaton In the circumstances posted in the question, that would cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

When doing redirect into the same file (`>`), shell may create/truncate the file before the `cat` command is invoked and the input is read (see: [Why doesn't “sort file1 > file1” work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7935512/55075)). If you want to filter the file, it's better to redirect the output into different file, or avoid redirection at all, for example:

```
grep -v 'Apple' readme.log | tee readme.log
```

The better and safer way is to use in-place editors which are designed for that kind of operations, e.g.

```
sed -i '.bak' '/Apple/d' readme.log
```

or use `ex` (part of Vim):

```
ex +g/Apple/d -cwq readme.log
```

Related:

- [Delete lines in a text file that containing a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5410757/55075) at SO
- [Redirect input from file back into same file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842/55075) at SO